# Can't validate tokens with lua

Tags: go, nginx, lua, access-token, openresty

I have a golang application. It creates an access token. I need to check the validity of a token using lua. Here is my lua code:

```
local jwt = require "resty.jwt"
function loadEnvFile(filepath)
    local env = {}
    local file, err = io.open(filepath, "r")
    if not file then
        return env, err
    end
    for line in file:lines() do
        if not line:match("^%s*#") and line:match("%S") then
            local key, value = line:match("^%s*([^=]+)=(.+)$")
            if key and value then
                env[string.gsub(key, "^%s*(.-)%s*$", "%1")] = string.gsub(value, "^%s*(.-)%s*$", "%1")
            end
        end
    end
    file:close()
    return env
end

local env = loadEnvFile("./.env")
if next(env) == nil then
    ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "Файл .env не содержит данных или не удалось загрузить его")
    -- Обработка ошибки загрузки файла
    return
end

-- Получение токена из запроса (в данном случае из заголовка Authorization)
local access_token = ngx.var.http_authorization
local secret_key = env["JWT_SECRET_KEY"]

-- Проверка наличия токена
if not access_token then
    ngx.status = ngx.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED
    ngx.say("Ошибка авторизации: Токен доступа отсутствует")
    ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED)
end

-- Проверка токена
local jwt_obj = jwt:verify(secret_key, access_token)

-- Проверка результата проверки токена
if not jwt_obj.verified then
    ngx.status = ngx.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED
    ngx.say("Ошибка авторизации: Неверный токен доступа")
    ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED)
end

-- Передача заголовков ответа и кода статуса
ngx.header.content_type = "text/plain"
ngx.status = ngx.HTTP_OK

-- Отправка ответа клиенту
ngx.say("Токен доступа: ", access_token)
ngx.say("Секретный ключ: ", secret_key)
ngx.say("Результат проверки: ", jwt_obj.verified)

ngx.flush(true)
```

Here is my server.conf:

```
events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  lua_package_path "lua-script/?.lua;/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/resty/?.lua;;";

  server {
    listen 80;

    location /api/pomo {
      access_by_lua_file <путь к lua файлу>;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:1323;
    }
    location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:1323;
    }
  }
}
```

On the localhost:80/api/pomo route, which I use, I always get an invalid token error. But on localhost:1323 the same token works correctly.

How do I check the validity of a token using lua??? That is, in the end, the structure should be like this request ↔︎ nginx(lua) ↔︎ golang. I run nginx with lua code through openresty.

Here is the go token generation code:

```
func GenerateToken(userID uint) string {
    claims := &JwtCustomClaims{
        userID,
        generateRandomString(32),
        jwt.RegisteredClaims{
            ExpiresAt: jwt.NewNumericDate(time.Now().Add(time.Hour * 72)),
        },
    }

    token := jwt.NewWithClaims(jwt.SigningMethodHS256, claims)

    signedToken, _ := token.SignedString([]byte(os.Getenv("JWT_SECRET_KEY")))

    return signedToken
}
```

I don't understand what's wrong with me

Comment: Please add `ngx.say(access_token, "||", secret_key)` right after `local jwt_obj = jwt:verify(secret_key, access_token)`. Then test again and share the output.

Comment: the problem was that jwt_secret_key from .env was taken in "".

Answer (score 1):

i solved the problem.
jwt_secret_key from .env was stored in lua in "". I just added the remove "" method and it worked.

Here is the lua code itself:

```
local jwt = require "resty.jwt"
local cjson = require "cjson"

function loadEnvFile(filepath)
    local env = {}
    local file, err = io.open(filepath, "r")
    if not file then
        return env, err
    end
    for line in file:lines() do
        if not line:match("^%s*#") and line:match("%S") then
            local key, value = line:match("^%s*([^=]+)=(.+)$")
            if key and value then
                env[string.gsub(key, "^%s*(.-)%s*$", "%1")] = string.gsub(value, "^%s*(.-)%s*$", "%1")
            end
        end
    end
    file:close()
    return env
end

local env = loadEnvFile("./.env")
if next(env) == nil then
    ngx.say(ngx.ERR, "Файл .env не содержит данных или не удалось загрузить его")
    return
end

-- Получение токена из запроса (в данном случае из заголовка Authorization)
local authorization_header = ngx.var.http_authorization
local access_token = nil

if authorization_header and authorization_header:find("Bearer") then
    access_token = string.gsub(authorization_header, "Bearer ", "")
end

-- Проверка наличия токена
if not access_token then
    ngx.header.content_type = "text/plain"
    ngx.status = ngx.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED
    ngx.say("Ошибка авторизации: Токен доступа отсутствует")
    ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED)
end

-- Проверка токена
local secret_key = env["JWT_SECRET_KEY"]
secret_key = string.sub(secret_key, 2, -2)
local jwt_obj = jwt:verify(secret_key, access_token)

-- Вывод содержимого объекта jwt_obj в логи Nginx
ngx.say(ngx.DEBUG, "jwt_obj: ", cjson.encode(jwt_obj))
ngx.say(secret_key)

-- Проверка результата проверки токена
if not jwt_obj.verified then
    ngx.header.content_type = "text/plain"
    ngx.status = ngx.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED
    ngx.say("Ошибка авторизации: Неверный токен доступа")
    ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED)
end

-- Извлечение времени выпуска (iat) и времени истечения (exp) из полезной нагрузки JWT
local iat = jwt_obj.payload.iat
local exp = jwt_obj.payload.exp

-- Отправка ответа клиенту
ngx.header.content_type = "text/plain"
ngx.status = ngx.HTTP_OK
ngx.say("Время выпуска (iat): ", iat)
ngx.say("Время истечения (exp): ", exp)
ngx.say("Токен доступа: ", access_token)
ngx.say("Секретный ключ: ", secret_key)
ngx.say("Результат проверки: ", jwt_obj.verified)

ngx.flush(true)
```